# crud in laravel 5.1.11 controller

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

**Insert Controller === Insert data to Database**

```
public function create() 
{
  return view('books.create');
}
public function store()
{
  $book=Request::all();
  Book::create($book);
  return redirect('books');
}
```

** My Url

http://localhost/laravel/bookstore/public/books

** Problem show in my browser

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
ErrorException in BookController.php line 40:

Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::all() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

into

use Request;

Answer (score 0):

Please use this
Please check have you used this after namespace

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

After that you can use this.

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{
  $book=$request->all();
  Book::create($book);
  return redirect('books');
}
```

I think this will help.